# What does X11cairo followed by a number mean in R

Tags: r

I  was wondering what does X11cairo in the following mean

```
> pdf("1_4.pdf")
> plot(output)
> dev.off()
X11cairo 
       2
```

Also sometimes the number following X11cairo is 2, sometimes is 1. What does the number imply?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `Value:` section of the help page for `dev.off()`:

> ‘dev.off’ returns the number and name
>   of the new    active device (after the
>   specified device has been   shut
>   down).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the number refers to the number of the active "device" which take numbers 1 - 63. If you have a plot window open and then run the above code, the active device becomes number 2 and so forth. Check out `?dev.off` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are more interested in, but I want to know why it is called "cario".

see [Cario lib page](http://www.rforge.net/Cairo/):

> Cairo is a graphics device for R which uses the cairo graphics library
>   to provide high-quality output in various formats including bitmap
>   (PNG, JPEG, TIFF), vector (PDF, PostScript, SVG) and on-screen (X11,
>   Windows). It supports alpha-blending (semi-transparent painting),
>   anti-aliasing and font embedding. Since the same engine is used for
>   rendering on-screen and off-screen, is possible to create output
>   WYSIWYG-like output.